# What is the meaning of "Full Servlet 3.1 signature support in Spring-provided Filter implementations" in Spring 5 new features?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets

Spring 5 brings "Full Servlet 3.1 signature support in Spring-provided `Filter` implementations" according to [The "What's New in Spring 5"](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What%27s-New-in-Spring-Framework-5.x)

But what does this feature mean? Is there any new Servlet 3.1 signature support added in spring 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a hint of what this means from some issues from Spring JIRA like the one [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/3012) and [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12097). Basically the Spring filter implementation ( typically used in Spring security) obviously used `ServletRequest`/`ServletResponse` parameters in `doFilter` method which were not fully Servlet 3.1 API compliant. With Spring version 5 the support has been complete in contrast to previous version where it was incremental ( or as a bug fix)